# Genetate GCOV report for multiple cpp files

Tags: c++, gcov, gcovr

I have 3 files in a folder. `one.cpp`, `one.hpp` and `main.cpp`. `one.hpp` has a class declaration. `one.cpp` has definition of functions in the class both under same namespace.Iam calling  a function from the class in main and including `one.hpp` in main. how can compile and run all these files to generate coverage using gcov ?

I tried generating seperate object files and creating an executable .Didn't work

Comment: The simplest way to build the program would be `g++ -I. main.cpp one.cpp`.  That will name the resulting program `a.out`, but you can specify a different name via a `-o` option.  I forget what option(s) you need to add to enable gcov tooling -- look it up in the manual.

Comment: If you enable code coverage in your compiler it will automatically generate gcno files for each object file. If you run an executable that was compiled with code coverage it will generate gcda files during execution (matching the gcdo files). gcda + gcno will be used to generate your report. You don't actually check you source files but your object files.

Comment: Did you read the manual? https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov.html#Gcov

Comment: Johns suggestion worked with some gcov specific modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Compiled code using `g++ -I. main.cpp one.cpp` as John Suggested. To get coverage object after compilation and execution Modified the line as `g++ --coverage -I. main.cpp one.cpp`.It generated `a.out` and required `.gcna` and `.gcda` files.Generated coverage report as i wanted.Thanks for the help.